# iOS custom keyboard has this other thing I don't want attached to it

Tags: ios, keyboard, inputaccessoryview, inputview

I'm building an iPad app. I have a custom screen keyboard attached to a text field, which all works. But when it pops up, there is this other thing on top of it, containing four controls. The down-arrow on the right makes it go away, but not permanently. The other three controls don't seem to do anything.

[The View I Don't Want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEnDw.png)

I don't want this thing. I haven't figured out how to make it go away in code. I tried setting the text field's inputAccessoryView to nil. Didn't help.

What is this thing? How do I make it go away? If I wanted to use it, how would I?

Answer (score 0):

Through another venue I received this, which works. Thanks to Gopal Krishna Reddy.

```
autocorrectionType = .no
inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = []
```